# CSS color part of background with a new color

Tags: css, html5-canvas, mask

I have a canvas element and some drawings inside that element. what I want to achieve is to change color of some parts. The canvas background is white, so maybe we can add a mask to color non-white parts of the canvas. the chosen part is a rectangle and therefore the mask shape is easy to achieve. but is it possible to change the color of some parts of canvas that are not white?
thanks in advance :-)

P.S. because the canvas is already filled and drawn, I can't change the elements inside unless i redraw everything which would take a lot of time.

Comment: You can use `globalCompositeOperation` after the drawing of a part with "source-in" value. Could you please add some example here, how you draw the part, and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: That was fascinating! Just what I as looking for, I've tried masks and clips but couldn't get this. But 'globalCompositionOperation' just worked magic! although I have to figure how to handle overlaps of foreground shapes... but that was a big step forward. thank again. if you post it  as an answer I will confirm it as accepted. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usage of globalCompositeOperation**

In some cases you can use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation`, but unfortunately there is no way to isolate only a part you want. All the previous drawings will be acting in composition.

Some examples of `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` usage. The first half of `canvas` is white, other on is transparent.
Circles have different colors: gray, black and blac with opacity 0.5.
Change globalCompositeOperation options to see what you get in different situation.

Firstly the circles are being drawn, then - yellow rectangle that has canvas size.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let w = canvas.width = 600;
let h = canvas.height = 180;

draw();

document.getElementById('gco-options').addEventListener('change', e => {
        draw(e.target.value);
})


function draw(gco_val='source-in'){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w/2,h);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120,90,80,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(300,90,80,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(480,90,80,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();   
    
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = gco_val;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    ctx.restore();
            
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = 'bold 24px san-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText('gray', 120, 90);
    ctx.fillText('black', 300, 90);
    ctx.fillText('rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 480, 90);
    ctx.strokeText('gray', 120, 90);
    ctx.strokeText('black', 300, 90);
    ctx.strokeText('rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 480, 90); 
    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<select id="gco-options" style="position: fixed; top: 5px; left: 5px">
    <option selected>source-in</option>
    <option>source-over</option>
    <option>source-out</option>
    <option>destination-over</option>
    <option>destination-in</option>
    <option>destination-out</option>
    <option>difference</option>
    <option>lighter</option>
    <option>copy</option>
    <option>xor</option>
    <option>multiply</option>
    <option>screen</option>
    <option>overlay</option>
    <option>darken</option>
    <option>lighten</option>
    <option>color-dodge</option>
    <option>color-burn</option>
    <option>hard-light</option>
    <option>soft-light</option>
    <option>exclusion</option>
    <option>hue</option>
    <option>saturation</option>
    <option>color</option>
    <option>luminosity</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got your problem. To solve this problem you must create nested inside the element.
Then you can specify the position,background-color of the element.
HTML code :

```
<div class ="default-div">
<p>This is just for example </p>
<div class = "trial-div"></div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.default-div{
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
.trial-div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:300px;
  margin-top:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

You can position the element as per your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I don't want to color it fully. I just want to change to the color of some part of the canvas (say only a rectangle inside it) such that non-white pixels inside that rectangle get a new color.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your questions, are you referring to something like this:

**Canvas Elements:**

```
<canvas id="bg" width="640" height="480">
</canvas>
<canvas id="fg" width="300" height="300">
</canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bg {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#fg {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```